# Current IPV4 Address used in Internet are classless or classfull addresses?

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6, ipv4

Well I had one doubt when I read it somewhere

IPV4 Class A,B,C address are used for IP network ( public IP network)

Then their is a concept of classless addressing

So what do we use on the Internet  today Classful Addressing or Classless Adressing

If we are using classless addressing then the CLASS E addresses should also be available to us for use. Please help ?

Comment: Regards the last question:  http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/oct/14/ipv4-exhaustion-what-about-class-e-addresses/

Answer (score 1):

Classless addressing has been with us for twenty years. Your source is a little out of date. But your question doesn't actually have a meaning. Every IP address range had its own netmask: there isn't just one for the entire Internet.